# cumulative average powerbi by month

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-sum

I have below dataset.

```
Math    Literature  Biology date    student
4   2   5   2019-08-25  A
4   5   4   2019-08-08  A
5   4   5   2019-08-23  A
5   5   5   2019-08-15  A
5   5   5   2019-07-19  A
5   5   5   2019-07-15  A
5   5   5   2019-07-03  A
5   5   5   2019-06-26  A
1   1   2   2019-06-18  A
2   3   3   2019-06-14  A
5   5   5   2019-05-01  A
2   1   3   2019-04-26  A
```

I need to develop a solution in powerbi so in output I have cumulative average per subject per month

For example

```
             April May  June July   August 
Math       |   2    3.5  3    3.75     4
Literature |   1    3    3    3.75    3.83
Biology    |   3    4    3.6  4.125   4.33
```

Can you help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This forum encourages help, but not answering homework questions on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a matrix visualization for this.

1. Create a month-year variable and use it in the columns.
2. Use Average of Math,Literature and Biology in values
3. Under the format pane --> Values --> Show on rows --> Select this

This should give the view you are looking for. You can edit the value headers to your requirement.